# Filtering a range of IP addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I want to ALLOW all IP addresses within a given range to RDP access my AWS EC2 instances.

The range is IPs which have all the same first 6 digits,  as in 232.244.*.*

In security groups I have tried the following security group rule: 
`232.244.0.0/16`

Where I thought the `/16` indicated to allow all IPs whose first 16 digits matched 232.244 part but clearly this is not correct? Any ideas what I need to change on my rule?

`0.0.0.0/0` works just to verify there is no other issue but obviously I don't want to leave that gaping hole in my server environment.

Comment: How did you choose this CIDR range? Where did it come from? You should check with the people who chose it because it is not a valid IP range.

Comment: After the edit your IP cidr is valid.  As you thought, a /16 will allow any host with an ip that starts with 232.244.  Are you sure that the IP you're trying to connect from is in that range?

Answer (score 1):

The `232.344.0.0/16` CIDR block is **invalid**.

Each number can range from 0 to 255. Therefore, **344 is an invalid number**.